# Why is my JavaScript second counter not working?

Tags: javascript, html, counter

I made a second counter in JavaScript. But my code is not working.

My problem: "First I pressed Start button, but seconds was not going on normally."

Here is my codes:

```js
var a = 0;
var Time = setInterval(Counter, 1000);
function startCounter() {
    setInterval(Counter, 1000);
}

function Counter() {
    a += 1;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}

function pauseCounter() {
    clearInterval(Time);
}

function resetCounter() {
    a = 0;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startCounter()">Start</button>
<br>
<button onclick="pauseCounter()">Pause</button>
<p>Seconds: <a id='seconds'>0</a></p>
<button onclick="resetCounter()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is following line:

```
setInterval(Counter, 1000);
```

In above line you are creating an interval but you are not assigning it to any variable. So its not being cancelled.

Before starting a new interval make sure to clear the last one.

You need to assign the new `setInterval` to `Time` each time

```js
var a = 0;
var Time;
function startCounter() {
    clearInterval(Time)
    Time = setInterval(Counter, 1000);
}

function Counter() {
    a += 1;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}

function pauseCounter() {
    clearInterval(Time);
}

function resetCounter() {
    a = 0;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startCounter()">Start</button>
<br>
<button onclick="pauseCounter()">Pause</button>
<p>Seconds: <a id='seconds'>0</a></p>
<button onclick="resetCounter()">Reset</button>
```

Comment: This code have a little problem. If I press Start button 2 times, seconds not going on normally. If my question have a problem, you can edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you defined Time, you set it as an interval preemptively, meaning that it starts instantly. And in `startCounter()`, you just created an unnamed interval, which you cannot clear.

```js
var a = 0;
var Time;
function startCounter() {
    clearInterval(Time) // prevent multiple intervals at same time
    Time = setInterval(Counter, 1000);
}

function Counter() {
    a += 1;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}

function pauseCounter() {
    clearInterval(Time);
}

function resetCounter() {
    a = 0;
    seconds.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <button onclick="startCounter()">Start</button>
    <br>
    <button onclick="pauseCounter()">Pause</button>
    <p>Seconds: <a id='seconds'>0</a></p>
    <button onclick="resetCounter()">Reset</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: Not enough - If clicking reset we get two counters

Comment: This code have a little problem. If I press Start button 2 times, seconds not going on normally. If my question have a problem, you can edit my question.

Comment: I've added a clearInterval before the setInterval so that there cannot be multiple intervals at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the interval but also use type=button and addEventListener

```js
let a = 0;
let time;

let seconds;

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    clearInterval(time);
    time = setInterval(counter, 1000);
  });
  document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener("click", pauseCounter);
  document.getElementById("resetBut").addEventListener("click", resetCounter);
});

function counter() {
  a += 1;
  seconds.innerHTML = a;
}

function pauseCounter() {
  clearInterval(time);
}

function resetCounter() {
  a = 0;
  seconds.innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
<br>
<button type="button" id="pause">Pause</button>
<p>Seconds: <a id='seconds'>0</a></p>
<button type="button" id="resetBut">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the seconds object like this.

```js
seconds = document.getElementById('seconds')
```

Comment: Not the problem. IDs on the page are shadowed by window.id too so seconds work although not recommended